# Storing and retrieving a KO ObservableArray from a HashTable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array that I am binding to from my aspx:

```
var contacts = ko.observableArray(),
```

When this is populated, I store the array in a hashtable so I don't have to retrieve the value from my service again (this is a very slow process so if I don't want to re-retrieve something I've already retrieved before):

```
var toHash = contacts();
contactsHash[query] = toHash;
```

My hashtable:

```
var contactsHash = {},
```

Here's what my observable array looks like when it gets stored (the key is a string):

[image: toHash]

Here's how I pull it back out:

```
if (contactsHash[query]) {
     contacts.removeAll();
     var retrieved = contactsHash[query];
     contacts(retrieved);
}
```

And here's what it looks like when I pull it back out:

[image]

This obviously causes me issues as the observable array doesn't get populated with the array I stored earlier... So something got mucked up in between, I've made absolutely sure that they key I'm storing and accessing with is the same as well. Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference. When you call `contacts.removeAll();` you are also clearing `contactsHash[query]` since they both point to the same object in memory.

**Try this**
`contactsHash[query] = toHash.slice();`

instead of
`contactsHash[query] = toHash;`

*edit:*
`slice()` returns a shallow copy of the specified portion of an array.

Comment: `toHash.slice()` clones the array, so it is no longer referencing the original array.

Answer (score 3):

The elements are disappearing due to the fact that objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. Clearing one clears another.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response, I had to accept eazimmerman's for completeness though.